# What does this symbol mean on an 1853 GLO map?

Tags: legend, land-survey, historical-maps

This is a segment of an 1853 GLO survey map from the Bureau of Land Management in Oregon.

Does anyone know what the wavy line with the light blue gradient running alongside denotes?

[image: 1853 GLO Map]

I've tried searching for some sort of map legend but have been unable to find one.

Comment: Please post a link to get the original high-rez photo.

Comment: This is a link to the original map.

https://glorecords.blm.gov/details/survey/default.aspx?dm_id=331950&sid=xluucjne.w4d&surveyDetailsTabIndex=1

Answer (score 1):

Could just be a stream.

Plat Survey shows a water bend cutting right of the water.

[image]